# Cant send data from form to component in livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

so this is my form script in `tambah-produk.blade.php`

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="submit">
                    {{-- <div class="mb-6 w-max">
                        <span class="text-gray-900 font-medium px-1">Foto Produk</span>
                        <label type="file" name="image-product" id="image-product" required>
                            <span>
                                <img src="assets/images/image.png" class="mt-4 img-preview w-28 h-28 border-2 rounded-xl hover:bg-slate-200 cursor-pointer" alt="">
                            </span>
                            <input class="hidden" type="file" id="image" onchange="previewImage()">
                        </label>
                    </div> --}}
                    <div class="mb-6">
                        <label for="nama-produk" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Nama Produk</label>
                        <input wire:model.defer="productName" type="text" id="nama-produk" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="Nama Produk" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-6">
                        <label for="sku-produk" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">SKU Produk</label>
                        <input wire:model.defer="productSKU" type="text" id="sku-produk" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="SKU Produk" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-6">
                        <label for="desc" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Deskripsi</label>
                        <textarea wire:model.defer="desc" id="desc" rows="4" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="Tulis deskripsi disini" ></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-6">
                        <label for="kategori" wire:model.defer="category"class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400">kategori Produk</label>
                            <select id="kategori" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500">
                            <option disabled selected>Pilih Kategori Produk</option>
                            <option value="Material Bangunan">Material Bangunan</option>
                            <option value="Perkakas">Perkakas</option>
                            <option value="Makanan">Makanan</option>
                            <option value="Minuman">Minuman</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-6">
                        <label for="harga-produk" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Harga Produk</label>
                        <input wire:model.defer="price"type="text" id="harga-produk" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="Rp" >
                    </div>

                    {{-- Button --}}
                    <div class="flex mb-6 gap-5 justify-end">
                        <button data-modal-toggle="tambah-produk" type="button" class="text-white text-sm px-10 py-2 bg-gray-400 rounded-lg"> 
                            Batal
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit" class="text-white text-sm px-10 py-2 bg-red-600 rounded-lg"> 
                            Save
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

and this is my `submit` function

```
public function submit(){

        $this->validate([
            'productName' => 'string',
            'desc' => 'string',
            'productSKU' => 'string',
            'category' => 'string',
            'price' => 'string',
            'image' => 'image|max:1024',
        ]);

        $this->photoPath = $this->image->store('images');

        dd($this->productName);
        Product::create([
            'productName' => $this->productName,
            'desc' => $this->desc,
            'productSKU' => $this->productSKU,
            'category' => $this->category,
            'price' => $this->price,
            'photoPath' => $this->photoPath
        ]);

        session()->flash('success','produk ditambahkan');

    }
```

when i press `save` button, nothing change on the database.